# How do you create a rails app without using all of resource in create,update,delete?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the rails guides tutorial creating a [blog app](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) after we create the rails app and create a resources in the routes then we start working on a form_for for creating a posts title and text in the guide it tells me that we need to add this line `<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>`

> the posts_path helper is passed to the :url option. What Rails will do with this is that it will point the form to the create action of the current controller, the PostsController, and will send a POST request to that route.

so what am trying to understand is the passing to 'create action' you see I have a simple app where i want is when a text is entered in the title field and the submit button is entered I want it to pass to the create action where I just out put the text in the create action view or another view, the rails guide goes through teaching the 'CRUD' but I just want to understand How to build an app that doesn't use 'CRUD' for instance an app that takes an input and outputs it in another view?

my form:

```
    <h1>Here Lets create a simple post</h1>

<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path  do|f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>

    <% end %>
```

posts controller:

```
    class PostsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end 

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)

    end

    def post_params
        params_require(:post).permit(:title)
    end
end
```

create view:

```
    <h1>THis is the post create action</h1>

<%= @post.title %>
```

routes:

```
    Learnnobase::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  root "welcome#home"
end
```

Right now am getting an error stating `uninitialized constant PostsController::Post` highlighting my create method? I've done so many rails app tutorials using 'CRUD' I really wanna learn building a simple app without using 'CRUD', I was trying to experiment with this app even though I do use the create action of "CRUD".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We generally use Rails to build database-backed applications, but for learning purposes, you can do it this way.

The problem you are facing here is: You are tyring to create an object of the Post class, that will be the model in the example you are referring to. The error comes up since you have not created the Post model.

To meet your requirement you can make your `create` action be:

```
def create
  @post = post_params #this will be a hash
end
```

Then change your view to:

```
<h1>THis is the post create action</h1>

<%= @post[:title] %>
```

Comment: In my view it outputs as expected thanks for your help but also how would I format the output like lets say I want to capitalize it I tries <%= @post[:title].upcase %> and got an error?

Comment: undefined method `upcase' for {"title"=>"jimmy"}:ActionController::Parameters

Comment: What if you try `@post = post_params[:post]` in your controller's create action?

Comment: @ManojMonga you should not have suggested such things, and btw it won't execute or serve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have started with rails, I would ask you how did your `posts/new` page load with `@post = Post.new` in `posts/new` action when you do not have `post` `model` file and class?

It is not possible. Second, with what Manoj Monga has suggested you to use `params` by assigning it to an `instance` `variable`(wrong way to do so with params), if you try to use `create_path` for `posts` resources which literally is `'/posts'` you would end up hitting `posts/index` action.
Rails has standard reserve action names like `:index(GET, /posts), :show(GET, /posts/:id), :new(GET, /posts/new), :create(POST, /posts), :edit(GET, /posts/:id/edit), :update(PATCH, /posts/:id)` You should not attempt at overriding their purpose.

What I understand that you did use `post` model class and loaded `posts/new` page, then you deleted `post` model class and tried with what you have asked about in your question. You should respect `Rails`' standards.